# Any Free Alternative for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having a little hard time using the SQL Developer, like when doing lengthy scripts and there's an error somewhere, I have to go at most line by line searching the error.  I recently shifted from Toad since it is not a free software anymore.  Do we have have any open sourced free alternative to SQL Developer?

Comment: You mean alternative to this? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html or to PL/SQL developer?

Comment: yes, alternative to SQL-Developer.

Comment: If you can update your answer with an example, perhaps someone will be able to show you how to quickly zero in on the line causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you only need a software that will check your query for errors, and that the error will be pointed out by line, personally I'm using this [site.](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)  I have been using it to check the errors line by line.

Answer (score 3):

All of these tools rely on Oracle for information on the location of an error. If you don't get that information in SQL Developer then you're not going to get it from another.